# enviar JSON desde Spring MVC a angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, jackson

Estoy intentando comunicar spring MVC con AngularJS, mando datos de AngularJS a spring pero no al revés, tengo un formulario de login, el cual recojo los datos y los envío a mi proyecto JAVA.

Esto funciona bien, ahora pretendo esos mismo datos devolverlo al index para mostrarlo debajo del formulario:

Aquí mi código JAVA, la primera función `saveLogin` recibe bien el JSON, al hacer una prueba con los mismo datos, los mando con `Loadlogin_json(user);` a la función que supuestamente tiene que devolverlo al index para mostrarlo.

```
@Controller
public class RespuestaLogin {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/savelogin_json" , method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes="application/json",headers = "content-type=application/json")
     public @ResponseBody String saveLogin(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        User user = mapper.readValue(reader, User.class);      
        Loadlogin_json(user);

        return "success";   
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
        public  void Loadlogin_json( User user)throws IOException {
            /*System.out.println("nombre: "+user.getName());


             return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);*/

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            File json = new File("index.json");
            mapper.writeValue(json, user);
            System.out.println("Java object converted to JSON String, written to file");
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
             new ResponseEntity<ObjectMapper>(mapper, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

A continuación muestro el código de AngularJS, al igual el `LoginService` de arriba funciona bien, pero el `RespuestaLoginService` no, adjunto el código a ver si podéis echarme una mano con el por que no recojo en AngularJS el JSON enviado.

```
var app= angular.module('login.loginService',[]);

app.factory('LoginService', ['$http','$q', function($http, $q){
        var self={
            login: function(datos){
                var dataObj = {
                        name : datos.usuario,
                        pass : datos.pass,
                };  

                var d=$q.defer();
                function genericSuccess (res) {
                      return res.data.data; // yes, really.
                    }
                var res= $http.post('savelogin_json', dataObj).then(function(success) {
                    return genericSuccess(success);
                  });

                return d.promise;
            }   
        };

        return self;
}]);

app.factory('RespuestaLoginService', ['$http','$q', function($http, $q){
    console.log("entra en angular");
    var self={
        respuestalogin: function(datos){

            var d=$q.defer();
            function genericSuccess (res) {
              return res.data.data; // yes, really.
            }

            $http.post("index",datos).then(function(success) {
                return genericSuccess(success);

            });

            console.log("FUE LLAMADO desde el servicio RespuestaLoginService login de angularjs");


            return d.promise;
        }

    };

    return self;


}]);
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51526/discussion-on-question-by-nose-ke-enviar-json-desde-spring-mvc-a-angularjs).

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS (Angular 1) no recibe nada porque esos servicios no están respondiendo nada. Deberás indicar qué van a devolver los servicios. Uno de ellos devuelve void y el otro String con un "success".

Answer (score 1):

Las peticiones de AngularJS (Angular 1) se realizan a través de AJAX, por lo que necesitas anotar tu controlador como `@RestController` y devolver directamente el objecto que desees.

Por ejemplo, si quieres devolver el mismo objeto que envías:

```
@RestController
public class RespuestaLogin {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public  User Loadlogin_json(@RequestBody User user)throws IOException {

    return user;

  }

}
```

En el controlador de AngularJS podrías ver la `response`:

```
$http.post("index",datos).then(function(response) {
  return console.log(response);
});
```